# restore system after "accidental" purge

Tags: apt, 18.04, data-recovery, purge

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

I installed biopython package with the install-suggested option, not realizing that it would also install the suggested packages of the suggested packages of the suggested ... So this got out of hand pretty extensively.

Since it installed a lot of crap I really didn't want I used

```
awk '!/^Start|^Commandl|^End|^Upgrade:|^Error:/ { gsub( /\([^()]*\)/ ,"" );gsub(/ ,/," ");sub(/^Install:/,""); print}' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

to find out the packages that were installed and used

```
apt purge [all i just installed]
```

But I believe this did also get rid of packages that were already installed before but appeared in the list. For example if I am trying to SSH onto my server nothing seems to happen.

What is the most elegant way to recover the state of my system before installing biopyhton?

PS: I have a backup from last week. But it only saves the content of the home folder so I believe it wouldn't affect installed packages.

PS2: I've been looking through /var/log/apt/history.log
and some stuff I installed is not appearing in there. For example build-essential is nowhere to be found.
Are there other locations where info about what was installed can be found?

Comment: Will I get all the packages back that I didn't install myself but came with the Ubuntu installation?

Comment: @Chris it might, it might not.  The problem is that what you probably 'uninstalled' was a good portion of those 'came with the installation' packages as well, and that could cause problems if some 'core' packages are gone.

Comment: That's what I'm worried about. For me the stuff I installed on my own is not so much of a problem. If I need this again I just can reinstall it. I'm far more worried about the stuff I that comes with the system and I don't realize I should have.

Comment: Reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage to restore the packages originally installed (though perhaps newer versions). Apt has built-in protections to prevent precisely this kind of mess - I *always* use them.

Comment: @user535733 great hint. When trying to do this apt prompted me to run apt --fix-broken install. Thx for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to use

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

it didn't work right away for me.
I had to run

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

followed by

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

This seems to have fixed the issue for me.